# I am trying to use the below code to mark a test passed or Failed with Browserstack

Tags: c#, appium, browserstack

I have seen the answers in Stackoverflow but those are not anything close to what I am using which is Appium C# against BrowserStack. I asked Browserstack but they said they can't help with code questions.

```cs
IWebElement Success = _IOSdriver.FindElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeAlert[@name='Success']");
string ExpText = "Success";
string ActText = Success.Text;
if (ExpText.Equals(ActText))
{
    Assert.AreEqual(ExpText, ActText);
    Console.WriteLine("Message verified Successfully");
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_IOSdriver).ExecuteScript("browserstack_executor: {\"action\": \"setSessionStatus\", \"arguments\": {\"status\":\"Passed\", \"reason\": \" Success not matched \"}}");
    _IOSdriver.ExecuteScript("String");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message Verification Failed");
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)_IOSdriver).ExecuteScript("browserstack_executor: {\"action\": \"setSessionStatus\", \"arguments\": {\"status\":\"failed\", \"reason\": \" Success not matched \"}}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can refer to the link: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/set-up-tests/mark-tests-as-pass-fail#c_sharp

and execute sample test if work then changes in your framework accordingly.

Comment: I have looked through the documentation but I do not know how to integrate it with my code.